# Remove specific data from a table which are common based on certain fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table EMPLOYEE as under:

```
Enroll Date STS EMP_ID  EMP_Name   DEPT    Rank OST BLOCK   
12-Jan-17    Q    123     ABC     ABC123    12  Y   1000    
14-Jan-17    Q    123     ABC     DEF123    12  Y   1000    
15-Jan-17    R    123     ABC     DEF123    12  Y   100 
15-Jan-17    R    123     ABC     DEF123    12  Y   200 
15-Jan-17    R    123     ABC     DEF123    12  Y   300 
20-Jan-17    R    123     ABC     DEF123    10  Y   300 
26-Jan-17    R    456     RST     DEF456    8   N   200 
26-Jan-17    R    456     RST     DEF456    8   N   300 
2-Feb-17     Q    123     ABC     ABC123    12  Y   300
```

Now i need to remove the duplicate rows for each emp_id (duplicate if EMP_Name, DEPT, OST and rank is same). If 2 rows have these 4 value same and enroll_date is different then i need not delete that row. And if 2 rows have same enroll date and the 4 fields (OST, EMP_Name, DEPT and rank) are same then i need to keep the row with highest block (1000 followed by 300 followed by 200 and so on)
So after deleting such data my table should have these rows:

```
Enroll Date STS EMP_ID  EMP_Name    DEPT    Rank    OST BLOCK   
12-Jan-17    Q   123       ABC     ABC123    12      Y  1000    
14-Jan-17    Q   123       ABC     DEF123    12      Y  1000    
15-Jan-17    R   123       ABC     DEF123    12      Y  100 
2-Feb-17     Q   123       ABC     ABC123    12      Y  300 
20-Jan-17    R   123       ABC     DEF123    10      Y  300 
26-Jan-17    R   456       RST     DEF456    8       N  200 
26-Jan-17    R   456       RST     DEF456    8       N  300
```

I tried using below query and will delete rows which have rn >1

SELECT enroll_date, STS, BLOCK, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT,RANK, OST, row_number() over ( partition BY emp_id, enroll_date,emp_name, dept, ost, rank ORDER BY enroll_date ASC, block DESC)rn
  FROM employee

But i am getting rn as 1 only everytime.

can someone check the issue here or suggest some other way to do so?

Comment: The three rows with 15-Jan all get rn as 1? Are the rimes for those date values all midnight - what does `to_char(enroll_date, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` show the time oart as for those (or all) rows? If they are not all midnight, should they be?

Comment: Please explain in more detail: "if **2 rows** have ....  then I need not delete **that row**". When you have TWO ROWS, which one is "THAT ROW"?

Comment: @Mathguy- 
"If 2 rows have these 4 value same and enroll_date is different then i need not delete that row" 
This means that if any 2 rows in the table have exactly same value (all the 4 column should have same value) for the columns OST, EMP_Name, DEPT and rank, then taht row needs to be deleted. But in same case if the enroll_date is different for any 2 rows which have exact same value for OST, EMP_Name, DEPT and rank, then we need to retain both rows.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `enroll_date` values have non-midnight times, so partitioning by those also made those combinations unique (even though they don't look it when you only show the date part).

My initial thought was that your analytic `row_number()` was partitoned by too many columns, and that you shouldn't be including the date value you want to order by - it doesn't really make sense to partition by and order by the same thing, as it will be unique. Reducing the columns you actually want to check against, perhaps to:

```
row_number() over (partition BY emp_id, emp_name, dept, ost, rank
  ORDER BY enroll_date ASC, block DESC)
```

would produce different ranks rather than all being 1. But I don't think that's right; that would probably make your secondary block ordering somewhat redundant, as you'll maybe be unlikely to have two rows with exactly the same time for one ID. Unlikely but not impossible, perhaps.

Re-reading your wording again I don't think you want to be ordering by the `enroll_date` at all, and you *do* want to be partitioning by the date instead; but, given that it contains non-midnight times that you apparently want to ignore for this exercise, the partitioning would have to be on the truncated date (which strips the time back to midnight, by default:

```
row_number() over (partition BY trunc(enroll_date), emp_id, emp_name, dept, ost, rank
  ORDER BY block DESC)
```

With your sample data as a CTE, including slightly different times within each day, and one extra row to get everything the same but the date, this shows your original `rn` and my two calculated values:

```
with employee (enroll_date, sts, emp_id, emp_name, dept, rank, ost, block) as (
  select to_date('12-Jan-17 00:00:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Q', 123, 'ABC', 'ABC123', 12, 'Y', 1000 from dual
  union all select to_date('14-Jan-17 00:00:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Q', 123, 'ABC', 'DEF123', 12, 'Y', 1000 from dual
  union all select to_date('15-Jan-17 00:00:01', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'R', 123, 'ABC', 'DEF123', 12, 'Y', 100 from dual
  union all select to_date('15-Jan-17 00:00:02', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'R', 123, 'ABC', 'DEF123', 12, 'Y', 200 from dual
  union all select to_date('15-Jan-17 00:00:03', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'R', 123, 'ABC', 'DEF123', 12, 'Y', 300 from dual
  union all select to_date('20-Jan-17 00:00:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'R', 123, 'ABC', 'DEF123', 10, 'Y', 300 from dual
  union all select to_date('26-Jan-17 00:00:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'R', 456, 'RST', 'DEF456', 8, 'N', 200 from dual
  union all select to_date('26-Jan-17 00:00:01', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'R', 456, 'RST', 'DEF456', 8, 'N', 300 from dual
  union all select to_date('2-Feb-17 00:00:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Q', 123, 'ABC', 'ABC123', 12, 'Y', 300 from dual
  union all select to_date('3-Feb-17 00:00:00', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Q', 123, 'ABC', 'ABC123', 12, 'Y', 300 from dual
)
SELECT to_char(enroll_date, 'DD-Mon-RR') as date_only,
  enroll_date, sts, block, emp_id, emp_name, dept, rank, ost,
  row_number() over ( partition BY emp_id, enroll_date, emp_name, dept, ost, rank 
    ORDER BY enroll_date ASC, block DESC) your_rn,
  row_number() over (partition BY emp_id, emp_name, dept, ost, rank
    ORDER BY enroll_date ASC, block DESC) my_rn_1,
  row_number() over (partition BY trunc(enroll_date), emp_id, emp_name, dept, ost, rank
    ORDER BY block DESC) as my_rn_2
FROM employee
ORDER BY enroll_date;

DATE_ONLY ENROLL_DATE         S BLOCK EMP_ID EMP DEPT   RANK O YOUR_RN MY_RN_1 MY_RN_2
--------- ------------------- - ----- ------ --- ------ ---- - ------- ------- -------
12-Jan-17 2017-01-12 00:00:00 Q  1000    123 ABC ABC123   12 Y       1       1       1
14-Jan-17 2017-01-14 00:00:00 Q  1000    123 ABC DEF123   12 Y       1       1       1
15-Jan-17 2017-01-15 00:00:01 R   100    123 ABC DEF123   12 Y       1       2       3
15-Jan-17 2017-01-15 00:00:02 R   200    123 ABC DEF123   12 Y       1       3       2
15-Jan-17 2017-01-15 00:00:03 R   300    123 ABC DEF123   12 Y       1       4       1
20-Jan-17 2017-01-20 00:00:00 R   300    123 ABC DEF123   10 Y       1       1       1
26-Jan-17 2017-01-26 00:00:00 R   200    456 RST DEF456    8 N       1       1       2
26-Jan-17 2017-01-26 00:00:01 R   300    456 RST DEF456    8 N       1       2       1
02-Feb-17 2017-02-02 00:00:00 Q   300    123 ABC ABC123   12 Y       1       2       1
03-Feb-17 2017-02-03 00:00:00 Q   300    123 ABC ABC123   12 Y       1       3       1
```

To identify the rows to delete you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT enroll_date, sts, block, emp_id, emp_name, dept, rank, ost
FROM (
  SELECT enroll_date, sts, block, emp_id, emp_name, dept, rank, ost,
    row_number() over (partition BY trunc(enroll_date), emp_id, emp_name, dept, ost, rank
      ORDER BY block DESC) as my_rn_2
  FROM employee
)
WHERE my_rn_2 > 1
ORDER BY enroll_date;

ENROLL_DATE         S BLOCK EMP_ID EMP DEPT   RANK O
------------------- - ----- ------ --- ------ ---- -
2017-01-15 00:00:01 R   100    123 ABC DEF123   12 Y
2017-01-15 00:00:02 R   200    123 ABC DEF123   12 Y
2017-01-26 00:00:00 R   200    456 RST DEF456    8 N
```

You'll need to decide what actually makes sense for your data and requirements though.

Comment: I think you are correct, edited the query and posting the anwer with that. It working now by changing the enroll_date with trunc function.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the row with the highest block on a given day, even of there are other rows with later times that day? You are ignoring the times - that may actually be what you do want, but I'd check that is correct before deleting anything. Without knowing what block represents, it just sounds a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a temporary table which will have all non duplicate values:

```
 create table employee_temp as
 with duplicates as (
 SELECT enroll_date, STS, BLOCK, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT,RANK, OST, row_number()     over ( partition BY emp_id, trunc(enroll_date),emp_name, dept, ost, rank ORDER BY enroll_date ASC, block DESC)rn FROM employee )
 SELECT enroll_date, STS, BLOCK, EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT,RANK, OST from duplicates where rn =1;
```